# Removing overlapping polygon boundaries within same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

We are building mosaic datasets for 100's of rasters (Topo sheets). Used QGIS Tile_Index to get the raster_topo_sheet's extent as vector. But the issue is, overlaps near the edges of all the topo sheets. Instead of manually correcting these edges for footprint creation, can't we merge/delete one boundary and make it seamless ?

[image]

1) Tried "Eliminate selected polygons" in qgis with alternate polygons selected (Largest common boundary). But result was not as expected.

2) Tried "Dissolve tool" in QGIS. [Removing overlapping/duplicate polygons in same layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133207/removing-overlapping-duplicate-polygons-in-same-layer-using-qgis). But same overlap exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**QGIS 3.4.1**

From Processing Toolbox:

1. `SAGA | Vector polygon tools` - **Polygon self-intersection** tool. This tool returns a new layer with sub-divided polygons (while only one of the duplicated overlapping area is retained).
2. `Vector selection` - **Select by expression** tool. Use an expression to select the sliver polygons (see below example).
3. `Vector geometry` - **Eliminate selected polygons** tool will remove these selected features. (I would suggest `Largest common boundary` option... it will give more naturally-looking output.)

---

(Example of the Step 2) It is hard to explain the Step 2 without showing sample pictures...

Use **Select by Expression** on the `Intersection` layer (output layer by the Step 1) to select sliver polygons. In this example I selected polygons which area are less than 7,000 m2. (Please decide this threshold value beforehand. I used `Measure Area` tool and visually checked the biggest sliver I wanted to remove.)

[image]

All slivers were successfully selected and highlighted, so I can merge them with the neighbor polygons.

[image]